# redirect and load view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, codeigniter-3

good morning im doing progresss with codeigniter :D

this is the model: im in a login page

```
$user_data= array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'logged_in' => true
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin','You are now loggedin');

                $this->load->view('users/home',$user_data);
```

but when the page is called the browser display this:

[image]

why the view doesnt load the correct view but display the content of the home view ?

if i change 
`$this->load->view('users/home',$user_data);`
with a `redirect()`, it doesn't work :(

thanks friends

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question what view do you want to load? The view that is loading now is the home view?

Comment: post your full code and login code as well

Comment: yes @Abdulla Nilam is correct show your full code because it seems all ok in your given code

Comment: You can redirect it to your Default Controller like 
`redirect(base_url()."Home","refresh");` You must define first your base_url